# C# Winforms RichTextBox. How to limit number of characters by size of rtb?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

How to limit number of characters by size of rtb? The same question for WPF textbox.

I tried to limit it by compare clientSize of rtb with `Graphics.MeasureString` and `TextRenderer.MeasureText`, but their both have some mistake in calculations, and `TR.MeasureText` cannot wrap one long word as rtb. So I have a big problem with long words.

In WPF I used `FormattedText` to get text size, but it also doesn't wrap long words.

About the logic: in paste command I tried to make Adobe Acrobat logics for text fields: when you paste long text in middle of other text, you paste only that number of chars which you can.

Sorry for my language.

Comment: For `WPF` you would use `TextTrimming` property on the `TextBox` [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming(v=vs.110).aspx). But again without any code we can only do guessing.

Answer (score 0):

For WPF <strike>simply use the "MaxLength" property of TextBox.</strike>

Pasting a text limits it to the set amount of characters, but keep in mind that a newline (CR LF - 2 characters) is also counted. If you paste it in middle of text- the pasted content will be limited to how many characters are left until MaxLength.

Since OP mentioned this is about the width, not length, this is the path to consider - trimming the text based on the wrapping mechanism of WPF with a `TextBox` that has a set `MaxWidth`.

```
    private void this_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox)
        {
            var textb = sender as TextBox;
            if (textb.LineCount > 1)
            {
                foreach (var change in e.Changes.Where(x=>x.RemovedLength == 0))
                {
                    for (int index = change.AddedLength; index > 0; index--)
                    {
                        textb.Text = textb.Text.Remove(change.Offset, 1);
                        textb.UpdateLayout();
                        if (textb.LineCount == 1)
                            break;
                    }
                    if (textb.LineCount == 1)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the .xaml for such TextBox

```
    <TextBox TextChanged="this_TextChanged" MaxWidth="200" Text="{Binding TextValue}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

This is only a rough example - trimming a pasted text works fine, however it doesn't work if you select a part of already existing text and try to replace it by pasting text - the problem comes from updating the Text within TextChanged, which fires it once more - pasting in such way without the:

```
   e.Changes.Where(x=>x.RemovedLength == 0)
```

causes the text in front of TextBox to be trimmed instead - probably fixable.

Comment: Yea, but i don't MaxLength. And i cannot calculate it because symbols has different widths. It's usefull only for monospace font.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the text length, not text width.
It will not be an easy task, but I have updated the answer with a route to consider.